# I can Review close votes, but I don't have more votes to cast!

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

This post is interesting to Seth, since he has been in a similar situation.

Well, I have no more close votes for the day. But I only reviewed 19 questions, hence I have still access to the review queue. BUT! since most of the questions needs to be closed, I have to skip all my way until I find a question that don't deserve to be closed or just not reviewing 20 questions for the day.

Is this really common and expected behavior?

Comment: Are you saying you should be banned from the close votes queue if you have no more votes? What do you want to happen (if you're out of votes)?

Comment: @minerz029 I can't do First nor Late answers review if I spend all my 40 votes before hand... so somehow unless is something by design... seems rather illogical that I can still review

Comment: Ref: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258718/i-can-still-review-in-the-cv-queue-after-running-out-of-cvs

Answer (score 1):

This also happens to the Low Quality Post queue and First post queue. It used to be if I ran out of close votes I couldn't review either of those queues because it would effect my reviewing.

Comment: MM... this is before you were a mod? Cuz' you know, mods doesn't have limits in the review queues.

Comment: @Braiam Look at the date ;P (yes, long before I was elected, I'm sure it still stands).