# Can we get more close votes?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close

Currently we only get 24 close votes a day. I find this much too limiting, I can use all 24 of those votes really quick and still find a use for 24 more votes. Is there any way we could get a couple more? Maybe 30?

This would *really* help with site moderation.

<sup>If anyone official reads this, can they check [this bug out too](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7400/i-can-review-close-votes-but-i-dont-have-more-votes-to-cast)?</sup>

Comment: +1 I always run out of close votes while reviewing

Comment: What about an extra close vote for every 2/3 votes you review in the [review queue](http://askubuntu.com/review/close)? It is sort of being rewarded a bit more mess cleaning up the rest of the mess then :D - Something like that, anyway.

Comment: @Wilf: That's a decent idea, similar to the flagging system (1 extra flag per 10 helpful flags)

Comment: Upping the amount of close votes (without strings attached, no need to make it complicated), that seems like it could be a sane idea. I'd like some time to double-check our policies and run some numbers before we make a decision, sound good?

Comment: @GraceNote Thank you so much! Yes that sounds great :-D

Comment: The biggest issue I run into is I basically run out of votes when I go through the review queue. That doesn't leave me with enough to help clean up the other parts of the site.

Comment: @GraceNote I don't want to be pesky, but is there any news on this?

Comment: @Seth My intent is to get to this by the end of the week.

Comment: @JorgeCastro there's also the close queue by # of votes in the 10k tools, in case you spend all your review slots.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a review of your close habits, the volume of stuff that comes to the site, and how it all crashes into this sort of flaming wreckage, there really is a need for increased.

We've thus **raised the amount of close votes on Ask Ubuntu to match Stack Overflow, at 50 votes**.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the mess ;P

Comment: Yeah! \o/ Just in time for 14.04, now we can get to work!

Comment: Why wasn't the amount of reviews increased?

Comment: @Braiam Simple and direct answer is that we were looking at closures, not reviews.